# Only allow websites to open apps to after user confirmation

Tags: applications, share-menu

There are links such as YouTube, Twitter, Facebook, Quora, Play store. etc. which can only be opened with one application.

If I accidentally tap on *“open inside Quora app”,* Android does not ask me for confirmation and directly switches to the Quora app.

## I would like Android **still to ask me for confirmation.**

Uninstalling the app is no solution for me.
**Sometimes, advertising websites enforce opening the play store.**

With an operating system, which is marketed and always shown off to be *the customisation god,* this is one of the least things to expect from it.

Answer (score 2):

> If I tap on "share using Twitter" using the Internet browser, cross-app access opens the Twitter app without confirmation. Because that is my only Twitter client.

If you "share using Twitter", you are explicitly asking to open *the* Twitter app on your phone. Instead try *share > copy to clipboard* and then paste that link you copied into a browser of your choice.

Or if you'd like to continue browsing thru the Twitter links inside the same browser, maybe press and hold to then open the link in a new tab. If simply clicking a twitter link automatically opens the Twitter app, see [Leon's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189989/102422).

Answer (score 1):

When clicking a link, e.g. some twitter.com/etc, Android will probably ask if you'd like to open it with the browser or the Twitter client. At that point, there should be a check box available saying 'Always open with...' and then the option you choose. If you untick that box, it will ask you again next time.

As I read your question (although no question marks involved), you should disable the Twitter client to open by default. You can do so by going to "Settings → Apps → Twitter client".

Comment: I dd this, but it still opens using the app. **The actual reason for my question is, that some websites automatically open random apps on my phone.**

Comment: Okay, then I am not sure what causes this. Could you elaborate more in your question? Especially what you mean by 'random apps' and give a detailed example when it happens? Maybe we can help with that additional information.

Comment: Sure, @LeonJosse.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to disable is called **App Links** [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html)

> Android App Links on Android 6.0 (API level 23) and higher allow an app to designate itself as the default handler of a given type of link. If the user doesn't want the app to be the default handler, they can override this behavior from their device's system settings.

To **DISABLE**:
Go to **Settings->Apps->Configure apps(settings icon in top)->Opening links** there you will see list of apps with their *supported links*, tap on any app and it will show supported links and options for that app, something like
[image: screen shot for default links]
Just tap on **Ask every time** and you are done.